# SPARQL - get name of city from DBpedia using latitude and longitude

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I use SPARQL endpoint https://dbpedia.org/sparql.

how to get the name of city from DBpedia using latitude and longitude.

I have used a code SPARQL but there is any response.

cordially

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

select ?nameCity
where
{
?nameCity a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City>.
?nameCity geo:lat ?lat.
?nameCity geo:long ?long.

FILTER(?lat =10 && ?long=10)
}
```

Comment: what does not work? Do you think there is any City located at exactly (10,10)? Did you check other cities in DBpedia? Have a look at [London](dbpedia.org/resource/London), it has `lat="51.507221"^^xsd:float` and `long="-0.127500"^^xsd:float`. So neither the precision nor the datatype in your query would match any of the data.

Comment: you can try `dbp:latd` and `dbp:longd` properties which have some integer rounded values, but even then you have to hope that exactly for this coordinates data in DBpedia exists. It's just exact match query, for anything beyond you have to use Virtuoso GeoSpatial functions: https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/tutorials/sparql/SPARQL_Tutorials_Part_11/SPARQL_Tutorials_Part_11.html

Comment: the closest cities are far away from your point: `SELECT ?city (?geo, bif:st_point (10, 10)) as ?distance)
WHERE
  {
    ?city geo:geometry ?geo .
    ?city a dbo:City .
    FILTER (bif:st_intersects (?geo, bif:st_point (10, 10), 300))
  }
ORDER BY 2`

Comment: thank you, I checked the city of London with this code in sparql. the result was empty  :                                                                                                                                                              PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>               
select ?nameCity
where      
{
?nameCity a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City>.
?nameCity geo:lat ?lat.
?nameCity geo:long ?long.

FILTER(xsd:float(?lat)  = 51.507221 &&   xsd:float(?lat)  = -0.127500 )
}

Comment: fair enough, London was a "bad" example, for some reason it's not a city in DBpedia: `select ?nameCity where {
 ?nameCity a dbo:Place. 
?nameCity geo:lat "51.507221"^^xsd:float . 
?nameCity geo:long "-0.127500"^^xsd:float . 
} ` - nevertheless, my original point remains. Exact match of points is mostly useless, needs floating numbers and your point `(10, 10)` is not in a city at all if I look at the map.